# Extracting Binary Stream inside an mp3

Tags: binary-analysis, digital-forensics

In the song Chisel by Pruient there seems to be what sounds like a binary octet stream starting at 4:43.

The section of noise has distinct sections punctuated with momentary silence which leads me to assume it is an executable file, and not an image which I would assume would sound entirely of solid static. How could I extract this and analyse it further?

[Spotify Link](https://open.spotify.com/track/2yPnjVXVxAfvxU6Ktb2sVA?si=a71e675f96664827)
[Youtube link at 4:40](https://youtu.be/mahrXWywu6M?t=280)

Comment: wording: everything in your computer is an octet stream, even and especially all sound files.

Comment: neither youtube nor spotify deliver sound as MP3 these days, so what do you want to extract from what? The fact that we can here some harmonic content kind of suggests this is really just audio that was properly encoded.